# ¿Como enviar un Dato desde una clase para que una funcion de JInternalFrame la reciba?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un `JInternalFrame` donde llamo una función que se encuentra en la clase `Trabajador`, esa función llena el `Jtable` que se encuentra en el `JInternalFrame`.

Ahora lo que quiero es pasar un valor por medio de un llamado a una función que se encuentra en  el JInternalFrame.

```js
//Esta funcion se encuentra en el JInternalframe es para poder hacer un llamado a la funcion de listar que se encuentra en la Clase.

    public Trabajador()
    { 
    initComponents(); 

    ListarRegistro("", "7"); 

    } 
    void ListarRegistro(String buscar, String cantidad) {

    //jtTrabajador  es el nombre del JTable
    Model_trabajador mdlU = new Model_trabajador();

    mdlU.MostrarRegistros(jtTrabajador, buscar, cantidad);
    //Funcion de la clase   Trabajador

    }

//Esta es la función que llena la tabla :

//Clase Trabajador

//Aqui importo el formulario

import sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Trabajador;
Trabajador frm = new Trabajador();


 public void MorstraRegistros(JTable tabla,String texto,String cantidad) {

    //Codigo para llenar la tabla


//Despues de llenar la tabla ago  una consulta aparte  para saber cuantos registro hay 

  String sql_total = "SELECT COUNT(idTraba) from trabajador";

    Statement st_pagina = cnx.createStatement();
    ResultSet pagina = st_pagina.executeQuery(sql_total);

    if(pagina.next()) 
    { 

    int total_registro = pagina.getInt(1); 
    int total= total_registro / Integer.parseInt(cantidad) + ((total_registro % 
    Integer.parseInt(cantidad) == 0) ? 0 : 1); 
  
 //Luego llamo a la funcion que se encuentra en el JInternalFrame.

 `frm.Prueba(total);`

    }
    }

//Esta es la funcion que resibiria el total:

public void Prueba(int total)
    {  

 jOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"valor obtenido "+ total);

    } 

//Pero me sale el siguiente error :

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.clases.Model_trabajador.MorstraRegistros(Model_trabajador.java:174)
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Trabajador.ListarRegistro(Trabajador.java:35)
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Trabajador.<init>(Trabajador.java:30)
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Inicio.registroTrabajadorActionPerformed(Inicio.java:270)
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Inicio.access$400(Inicio.java:18)
 at sistema.gestion.logistica.view.Inicio$5.actionPerformed(Inicio.java:130)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)`
```

¿Alguien sabe porque y como poder solucionarlo ?